# Why do Javascript events differ from actual user events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Why do Javascript events differ from actual user events? I'm trying to update a `select2` input from javascript.

If I use...

```
$('#s2id_autogen12').val("Single").trigger("input");
```

...to select the value "single" from the a `select2` input, the value seems to change (although "none" is still visible), but events don't actually fire, and the drop down appears as though the user was in the middle of an action (extending below the input box as though they were in the middle of a selection and freezing there).

`Select2` seems overly verbose and complicated. I've removed a bunch of Angular to make the generated HTML structure easier to view below.

[Select2 input/select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFwhY.png)

I tried adding...

```
$('[Name="IO:4d4240604f235600d70f4c111310c728"]').val("Single").trigger("change");
$('[Name="IO:4d4240604f235600d70f4c111310c728"]')[0][1].selected=true;
```

...but I simply can't get the Select2 to update programmatically. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted a screenshot of the code instead of the actual code.

However it appears your problem is a typo. "Single" should be "single".

Try the following:

```
$('[Name="IO:4d4240604f235600d70f4c111310c728"]').val('single').trigger('change');
```

Note the lowercase `single`;

Comment: [thumps head on desk] Thank you :)